# How do I make changes to a named range in google sheets propagate immediately?

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges

I'm using Google Sheets to calculate my goals for weight lifting.  Different workouts are based on different percentages of my high score for each lift.

I had been calculating each day's plan with something like "=CEILING((0.8*A3/5), 1)*5" to represent 80% of whatever the hell was in A3, rounded to something divisible by five.  This was not maintainable.

What I'm working on now is using the script editor to provide custom functions.  "=FIVES('bench')" gives me my bench press progression for five reps.

That works great, except for when I change values.  I put a named range on each of my max lifts so I could call getRangeByName get the value by name instead of by cell coordinates.  But the functions I made don't get called again so I keep seeing stale values, even after refreshing the page.

I found another post suggesting that getRangeByName had a second arg which could be set to now() to refresh the cache now.  Tried that and it looks like that was out of date.  I haven't found any other info on a named range being cached.

How can I tell my script that it needs to re-run when a named range gets updated?  Is there some sort of observer/listener/watcher in sheets?  If not, I'm open to techniques - named ranges were just the first thing I bumped into for naming my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's script caching was never going to allow that to work without shenanigans.  The expectation is that `foo('bar')` will be deterministic, always returning the same thing.  I'd been passing the named range's name, hoping I could use getRangeByName and using the name as a label.

Instead I'm just using the range as an arg and passing a second string as a label:  `foo(bar, "Bar label")`.  It's a little more verbose, but much less so than the stuff I was trying to trick the script server with.  Don't fight the framework, folks.